# Duplicating Vertex Groups

Tags: particles, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have made a plane, and I have added one Vertex Group to it, and weight painted it as I desired. I then want another vertex group, but I want to duplicate the initial one, because I want the second vertex group to share the same weight paint as the first one, and I also want to add additional weight paint to the second vertex group.

Is there a way to duplicate vertex groups on the same object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can duplicate a vertex group from the drop down menu underneath the delete (-) button.

[image: Vgroup copy]

Comment: That iS THE WORSE UI. Its a down arrow that just loosk like a redundant scroll arrow.  Should be a "..." to show there are more options.

Comment: Omg the ui is so bad, I thought the same thing and your comment "solved" it for me.